# How to get Svelte reactivity to display changes to array

Tags: svelte

I am attempting to get Svelte to react to changes in an array. In my example [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2859cc2f0a9249d7a7709d1cf20aeec5?version=3.52.0) the array is changed, but the html output does not reflect this. What should I do?

```
<script>
    $: objs = [] || getObjects(objs);

    function update(){
        getObjects(objs);
    }

    function getObjects(objs) {
        objs.push('a');
        objs = objs
        console.log(objs);
        return objs;
    }
</script>

<h1>Lists</h1>
{#each objs || [] as obj}
    <div>
        { obj }
    </div>
{/each}
<button on:click={update}>Update</button>
```

Comment: svelte don't react to `.push()` but only to `=` so you can use spread syntax `...` instead, I hope it can be useful to you

Comment: Included an assignment - still doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by seeing here in this docs: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects

we can see for making reactive we have these 2 forms:

- old way

```js
objs.push("a");
objs = objs;
```

- ES6 spread syntax:

```js
objs = [...objs, "a"];
```

and there isn't any need for extra assignments `= []`, `||` that create those bugs, for me the easiest way is this:

```html
<script>
  let objs = []

  function update() {
    objs = [...objs, "a"];
  }
</script>

<h1>Lists</h1>

{#each objs as obj}
  <div>{obj}</div>
{/each}

<button on:click={update}>Update</button>
```

---

don't use always `$:` unless you have 2 or more data calculations or something that changes often in relation to another variable.

in this situation, a simple `let` variable is enough here since we change only the same variable.